# Logic begin method (java.security.cert.X509CRL) isRevoked

Tags: java, security, ssl, x509

Just wondering if someone knows what is the logic behind the method isRevoked from X509CRL class.

In the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CRL.html#isRevoked(java.security.cert.Certificate)) is only saying that this method validates if the Certificate object passed as parameter is in the list, but doesn't say which fields it compares (Serial Number, Issuer DN, etc).

```java
Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getString("x509_certificate").getBytes("utf-8")));      

CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509"); 
URL crlURL = new URL("http://www.certificadodigital.com.br/repositorio/lcr/serasarfbv2.crl");
InputStream crlStream = crlURL.openStream();
X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) certFactory.generateCRL(crlStream);        
System.out.println(crl.getIssuerDN());      


if (crl.isRevoked(cert) {
  System.out.println("revoked");
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a batch job to load some CRLs and check if the certificates that I have in my database were revoked, then flag them as revoked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to need to check the source/decompiled code as the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/idmanage.1012/b15569/oracle/security/crypto/cert/X500Name.html#equals_java_lang_Object_) for this area are a laugh, and **the behaviour is implementation specific**.

In the Oracle VM, the CRL object checks that the serial and the `X500Name` is the same... now the Voodoo happens inside `X500Name.equals()`, as it creates the DN based on all the name attributes from the CRL and certificate.

I'm sorry I cannot be more specific. My suggestion is: debug the code and put a breakpoint in `CRL.isRevoked()` and check from there on.

Comment: What do you mean with 'put a breakpoint in crl.isRevoked and check from there on'? It's hard to test this logic once I need to have a revoked certificate and pass to the 'isRevoked'. May I can find on the internet some revoked cert from a certain CRL to test.

Comment: Yep. Verisign has a [test site with a revoked certificate](https://test-sspev.verisign.com:2443/test-SSPEV-revoked-verisign.html). You just need to export the certificate from your browser.

Comment: The link is not working :-( trying to find another one